# Deploy multiple rails applications on same dns using apache and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, apache2, uri, passenger

I have setup the apache + passenger in my ec2 server.
When i try

```
    http://ec2-***-***-***-**.ap-*-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

output:

```
    It works!

    This is the default web page for this server.

    The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Next is

```
  ec2-***-***-***-**.ap-*-1.compute.amazonaws.com is mapped to a dns, say myserver.com
```

Now i want to run multiple rails applications here, like if i have app1, app2 and app3 rails applications.

myserver.com/app1, myserver.com/app2 and myserver.com/app3 should load the respective applications.
I looked into some tutorials under

```
            Deploying Rails with Sub URI: or creation of symlinks
```

but was unable to get a clear understanding. Can someone point me to some tutorials or give some basic understanding.

passenger version is 3.0.18

Comment: Does this help ? http://kibyegon.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/deploying-multiple-rails-apps-on-apache-using-phusion-passenger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RailsBaseURI).

It makes use of RailsBaseURI.

Example Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.phusion.nl
    DocumentRoot /websites/phusion
    <Directory /websites/phusion>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /rails                   # 
    <Directory /websites/phusion/rails>   # 
        Options -MultiViews               # 
    </Directory>                          # 
</VirtualHost>
```